# Determining cause of excessive memory usage in Passenger instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, passenger

I have a Rails app that occasionally has Passenger instances using massive amounts of memory. For example, most instances of the app consume 150-250MB of RAM, but there is currently one that is using 2GB - huge difference. What is the recommended method to track down the cause of this? Thanks.

Comment: Struggle with it, give up, and set PassengerMaxRequests.     Then hang your head in shame when this workaround becomes permanent.  http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxRequests

Comment: Haha, I've already gone down that route. Thing is, the last one I saw with that huge memory usage was after only 50 requests, so I decided that I didn't want to drop PassengerMaxRequests that low and to continue the quest for a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time it's not memory leaking, it's bloat: https://blog.engineyard.com/2009/thats-not-a-memory-leak-its-bloat

Comment: Thanks Hongli, the tools mentioned in the article appear to be just what I need here.

Comment: Great. Could you select my answer as the preferred one?